# How to make UIScrollView behave like a horitonzal collectionView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

Im aware UIScrollView scroll direction can be changed to horizontal but what im having a hard time understanding is how can i programmatically add multiple images(20+ images) to it as it scrolls (thus increasing the content width allowing it to behave like as UICollectionView?

*I apologize in advance is my question is a bit vague im quite new to swift programming and not that great at speaking english*

Comment: Use a `UICollectionView`! If you have content that is too big for the screen, but simple (large amount of text) use a scrollview (`UITextView` is already a `UIScrollView`). If your content consists of multiple elements always use a `UICollectionView`. There are very few exceptions.

Comment: At the moment you are also asking two questions: Make a `UIScrollView` behave like a `UICollectionView`? Add a `UIScrollView` to a `UICollectionView`? Update your question to be clear and simple.

Comment: I not too sure how to add a collectionView to add colectionViewCell thats why i wanted to add the UIScrollView (thought the process would be easier

Comment: I am sorry to say it will not be easier. If you cannot implement UICollectionView you can not create your own version of it. The easiest way is to take your time and learn the basics. Start with simple stuff and build all the awesome apps with some experience. It might all seem really hard at the moment, but your learning speed will improve. It is better to start small now and be good at that. The harder stuff will get you frustrated.